# Printing Div Content - Crashing

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm trying to print the contents of a div, I am able to do this but it seems that anytime it generates it crashes, leaving me unable to go back. And if I am printing a lot of pages it just makes the tab load until the browser asks me if I should close the tab or wait.

Here's what I have. (Help from Stackoverflow)

```
<div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <button id="print" onclick="printContent('content');" class="btn btn-info">Print</button>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-12" id="content"> 
  DYNAMIC PHP CONTENT IS GENERATED HERE
</div>

<script>
  function printContent(el){
  var restorepage = $('body').html();
  var printcontent = $('#' + el).clone();

  $('body').empty().html(printcontent);
  window.print();
  $('body').html(restorepage);
 }
</script>
```

Comment: This code runs and prints perfectly inside a test server, perhaps the problem lies within the `DYNAMIC PHP CONTENT IS GENERATED HERE` section. Is it possible to see what PHP generates?

Comment: This is working fine in chrome Version 68.0.3440.106 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: PHP generates user profiles, that are separated by page. Essentially allowing me to print each user is the system. there is about 487 records, I don't know if that is why it crashes

Comment: It could also be your browser, a broken package, a missing driver, etc. Please post the relevant code, as the problem is not in the current post, which makes it hard to answer your question.